# SQL percentage with rows same table with different where condition

Tags: sql, vertica

I want to do a query like:

```
 select 
     count(asterisk) where acción='a'/count(asterisk) where acción='b' * 100 
 from 
     same_table 
 grouped by day
```

but I don't want use subquery, is it possible with joins?

Comment: What DBMS are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

I`m not sure the syntax is correct, but you can use something like this:

```
SELECT  day,
        SUM(CASE WHEN "acción" = 'a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SUM_A, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN "acción" = 'b' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SUM_B, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN "acción" = 'a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SUM_A / SUM(CASE WHEN "acción" = 'b' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100 AS result
FROM    your_table
GROUP BY day
```

The concept is to actually sum the the values that you need, instead of count.

Comment: `acción` probably needs to be quoted: `"acción"`